# How to unregister as delegate?

Tags: delegating

When I try to redelegate a former baker (delegate) the error is:

```
Delegate deletion is forbidden (tz1.....)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing a delegate of a baker is disallowed in the current protocol (005). You can however transfer your balance to another account.